# Why does the || operator not work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to paginate using Node.js and Express and I want if the `slug <= 0`, `slug = 1`.

```
new(req, res, next) {
        let perPage = 16;
        //let page = req.params.page <= 0 ? 1: req.params.page; //This work
        let page = req.params.page || 1; //BUT this NOT work, please explain for me

        Product 
            .find()
            .skip((perPage * (page - 1)))
            .limit(perPage)
            .exec((err, products) => {
                    Product.countDocuments((err, count) => { 
                        if (err) return next(err);
                        res.render('product/index_product', {
                            products, 
                            current: page, 
                            pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage) 
                        });
                    });
            });
    }
```

I used the `||` operator to solve it but it does not work, I don't know why.

Comment: It will work if `page` is the number `0`. It does not work with any other number value or any string of length > 0.

Comment: Whats wrong with using `req.params.page > 0 ? req.params.page : 1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of the page being 0, query string parameters are parsed as *strings*.

`req.params.page <= 0 ? 1` works because `'0'` is, lexiographically, indeed `<= 0` (when then `0` on the right gets implicitly coerced to `'0'`).

```js
console.log('0' <= 0);
```

But `'0'` is not falsey, so

```
let page = req.params.page || 1;
```

is

```
let page = '0' || 1;
let page = '0'
```

Convert the page to a number first.

```
const paramPage = Number(req.params.page);
const page = paramPage || 1;
```

In the case of the page being *negative*, `let page = req.params.page || 1` wouldn't make sense anyway - negative numbers are truthy too. If that's a possibility in your code, your original approach of

```
const page = req.params.page <= 0 ? 1:
```

is the best one there is.